# What's wrong with Detours hook applying to CreateFile?

Tags: winapi, hook, detours

I ran into some troubles when attempting a Detours hook on CreateFile in this small program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{

    HANDLE file;
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten, pos;
    TCHAR msg[1000];

    std::cout << "Start creating file \"SampleFile.txt\"" << std::endl;
    file = CreateFile(L"C:\\TestHook\\SampleFile.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    std::cout << "\"SampleFile.txt\" added into C folder" << std::endl;

    CloseHandle(file);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a DLL applied:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include "C:\Detours\Detours-4.0.1\include\detours.h"


static HANDLE(WINAPI* TrueCreateFile)(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile) = CreateFileW;

__declspec(dllexport) HANDLE WINAPI MyCreateFile(LPCTSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD 
    dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile)
{
    HANDLE hookFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\TestHook\\hookYouGo.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    std::cout << "CreateFile() is hooked...Meet other file name than you want" << std::endl;     
    CloseHandle(hookFile);

    return hookFile;
}

BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;

    if (reason_for_call = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)TrueCreateFile, MyCreateFile);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Once executing in Visual Studio '19 (OS Windows 10), it adds a new file into the target folder, but another than I expect. Instead of hookYouGo.txt, SampleHook.txt appears there as if hook attachment failed. Looking into API monitor after process finish, I don't find any evidence that DLL was applied as orderly as well. In command line, it's just the same, since I launch withdll.exe that runs into outputs like statements on SampleFile, but DLL stuff seems beyond that process. Both withdll.exe and main func program and DLL are inside the same folder, sure.

Comment: Your hook function isn't calling the original function (`TrueCreateFile`), it's calling the hooked function recursively. Surprised it doesn't end in a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way, you must get the function address in order to hook it.

Like this:

```
static HANDLE(WINAPI* TrueCreateFile)(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile);

TrueCreateFile HookCreateFile;

HookCreateFile = (TrueCreateFile)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("Kernel32.dll"), "CreateFile");
```

Then do the actual hooking:

```
DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)HookCreateFile, MyCreateFile);
```